# How to get a date in variable for AngularJS using md-datepicker

Tags: angularjs, datepicker

I am able to show the calendar using md-datepicker.

controller:-

```
angular.module('plunker').controller('mycont', function(){
      this.myDate = new Date();
      this.isOpen = false;   
    });
```

View:-

```
<body ng-controller="mycont" ng-cloak>
   <section layout="row" layout-sm="column" layout-align="center center" layout-wrap></section>
   <md-datepicker ng-model="ctrl.myDate" md-placeholder="Enter Date" md-open-on-focus></md-datepicker>
</body>
```

I am able to show the calendar, but I want to know where the value of date selected is saved so that I can print the selected date

---

I was trying

```
<body ng-controller="mycont" ng-cloak>
   <section layout="row" layout-sm="column" layout-align="center center" layout-wrap></section>
   <md-datepicker ng-model="ctrl.myDate" md-placeholder="Enter Date" md-open-on-focus></md-datepicker>
   <p>The Date you picked is  {{ctrl.myDate}}</p>
</body>
```

In case you want to see rest of the code:-
http://plnkr.co/edit/n84v9Cxug67f4ikTuyGf?p=preview

Comment: Is your value not displaying in {{ctrl.myDate}} ?? as I am sure you must be getting the selected date value in this object

Comment: I saw the plnkr you shared, and I can see the date in {{ctrl.myDate}} variable.